# ¿Cómo puedo eliminar las lineas de un texto que tienen iguales el segundo campo?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, raspbian

Para ordenar un archivo temp.txt como este por el tercer campo

```
Alcorcón;Madrid;calle Sapporo
Móstoles;Madrid;calle Luces
Pozuelo;Madrid;calle Ancha
Toledo;Toledo;calle Mayor
```

Utilizo :

```
cat temp.txt |sort --field-separator=';' --key=3 > tmp_2.txt
rm temp.txt 
mv tmp_2.txt temp.txt
```

Y correctamente, me da:

```
Pozuelo;Madrid;calle Ancha
Móstoles;Madrid;calle Luces
Toledo;Toledo;calle Mayor
Alcorcón;Madrid;calle Sapporo
```

Y ahora lo que necesito es que me ordene por el segundo campo y me de sólo un resultado por provincia, eliminando el resto, o sea:

```
Pozuelo;Madrid;calle Ancha
Toledo;Toledo;calle Mayor
```

He intentado:

```
cat temp.txt |sort --unique --field-separator=';' --key=2 > tmp_2.txt
rm temp.txt 
mv tmp_2.txt temp.txt
```

Y

```
cat temp.txt |sort --field-separator=';' --key=2 --unique > tmp_2.txt
rm temp.txt 
mv tmp_2.txt temp.txt
```

Sin resultado alguno.

Trabajo con Raspbian, con lo que no me funcionan códigos como este:

```
sort -u -t, -k 2,2
```

Comment: es decir, ¿quieres la primera línea de cada columna segunda ordenando alfabéticamente?

Comment: No hace falta el `cat`, el `sort` sabe leer ficheros, entonces en vez de `cat foo | sort`, siempre puedes hacer simplemente `sort foo`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### La respuesta es awk.

```
awk --field-separator ";" '!salida[$2]++' temp.txt > temp.txt.nodup
# o tambien, que es lo mismo pero menos verboso
awk -F ";" '!salida[$2]++' temp.txt > temp.txt.nodup
```

Lo que hace es que se crea en el array `salida` una clave con un valor del segundo campo separado por `;` y lo aumenta en 1 en post-incremento. Si el campo no está en el array, entonces lo muestra como falso, lo cual es bueno porque indica que ese no está duplicado, entonces la negación sirve para que ese se imprima.

El punto de aumentarlo en 1 es que eso crearía una especie de array de frecuencias, donde, después de que ingresó por primera vez, aumenta en uno. `awk` evaluaría la primera vez como falso (porque no se encuentra ahí) y con la negación sería verdadero y lo imprimiría, las siguientes veces lo evaluaría como verdadero porque ya tiene valores mayores que 0, pero como lo negamos, entonces muestra como falso y ya no imprime esos valores.

Comment: Perfecto, es exactamente lo que me hacía falta. Muchas gracias Marco.